# How can I make my page slide up when the banner decreases in size?

Tags: html, css, image, height

The CSS for my header banner image is as follows:

```css
header {
  background-image:url(grassrootsheader.png);
  background-size:100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:180px;
}
```

My image currently shrinks and adjusts to fit the wrapper size.

The problem is that it shrinks in `height` and leaves an unsightly white space between the `header` and the `h1` element.

I imagine this is because I have the `header` height set at a fixed `180px`.

If I don't set a value for `header` height, the image wont load. I am able to get parts of the image to load if I insert text or if I set some sort of value for the `header` height (`3em`, or `180px`, percentages don't work) however, I don't want any text in the `header` and setting a fixed value for height defeats the purpose of

Comment: Could you post the HTML and any other CSS that is being effected?

Comment: Have you tried using background-size:cover?

Comment: I think my issue is that i'm trying to add a background image with no content.  If there is no content, the background won't be revealed.  I want the background image to appear on all of my pages without text.